# Google Maps addListener does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the HTML code below I want to have an alert when a map is changed (e.g. zooming, dragging, clicking).

That alert will be changed in future to show the corner coordinates when dragging, zooming or clicking. The button "Get Corners" will then be omitted (that works perfect now).

I have tried a lot of advices from numerous websites. But still no success.

The addListener for the alert does not work. Also using addDomListener instead does not work. What is the culprit in this code?

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>      
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<body>
<script>
   var map;
   function initialize()
   {
    var mapOpt = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(41.5,2.0),zoom:10, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE};
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt); 
   };
</script>

<script>
  function getCorners()
  {
   var bounds = map.getBounds();
   var ne = bounds.getNorthEast(); 
   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
   document.getElementById('ne').innerHTML = ne;
   document.getElementById('sw').innerHTML = sw;
  }
</script>

<! THIS addListener SCRIPT DOES NOT WORK>
<script>
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function()
  {
   window.alert("Map clicked");
  });
</script>

<script>
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);  
</script>
<p id="ne">NE</p>
<p id="sw">SW</p>
<button onclick="getCorners()">Get Corners</button> 

<br><br> 
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move the listener code inside the initilize function

```
function initialize()
{
  var mapOpt = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(41.5,2.0),zoom:10, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE};
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt); 
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
      window.alert("Map clicked");
  });
};
```

Comment: @Michael, and scaisEdge: Putting the addListener in initialize function worked! Many thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 2):

This is because `google.maps.event.addListener` is called before the browser even knows about your maps object. Probably there are also console errors.
Put this code into  `initialize()` then it should work.

It would in general be recommendable to put all scripts shortly before the  end of the body tag, after all HTML elements are defined including e.g. the div holding the map. Also the splitting of the scripts is kind of confusing and seems not to be necessary.

Comment: I need to add click event listener for marker which is created dynamically in map click event. However, in this case marker event is not triggered. What do I do? Have not found anything in this regard in Internet.